# CloudFoundry: nginx for serving static content on top of Gunicorn (Docker)

Tags: docker, nginx, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am currently running a Gunicorn server in a Docker container serving both a Flask application and static content (on Swisscom CloudFoundry).

What is the correct way to set up nginx as a reverse proxy for serving the static content? I assume the Staticfile buildpack is not the way to go?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you seeing a problem with your current set up? If so, what is the problem?

Comment: It is recommended in the Gunicorn docs (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html), and nginx is far more suited and optimized for serving static content if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: My question is do you need that? Adding Nginx is going to make things more complicated. If you have a small app with light traffic, to be perfectly honest, you're just wasting your time adding in Nginx. Run w/out it and spin up a second or third instance of your app if you need to scale up. If you find that you legitimately need to more efficiently deliver static file, like if a huge percentage of your time is spent serving up static files you could look at what I'm posting in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cloud Foundry, it's super easy to spin up an extra instance or two to scale your app up and handle more load. I would recommend doing this as it's dead simple and should work for really any app type. That and look at client side caching. You can reduce your the load on your server generated by requests for static files by simply having files cached client side.

If you really are serving up a lot of static file and it's not cost efficient to scale up additional instances of your app, you can do the following:

1.) Push your Flask app using the Python buildpack. This will be given the main route for your app.

2.) Push your app files using the Static File buildpack using a separate hostname or context path. For example: static.example.com or www.example.com/static.

By doing this, you will route any requests to the `static.example.com` route or the `www.example.com/static` route and path to your static files being hosted by Nginx (courtesy of the Static File buildpack). Requests to your main route or not to the static path, will end up going to your Python app. The platform handles this and makes sure the routes go to the correct app based on the routes you define for each app.

The only downside is that this relies on you having static content separated out, so that you can map a custom route or custom route and path for your static content. That said, I don't think this should be an issue because you're running Flask. If it is an issue, you can always map multiple routes + paths. Depending on how your files are structured, this may require a lot of routes + paths to be mapped.

As I mentioned above, this has the advantage of relying on the platform to route static requests to one app and all other requests to another app. If you were to try and set up Nginx as a proxy, you'd be adding more layers of proxies and more latency to your requests.