# CloudFoundry: How to use multiple buildpacks? (NGINX + Django/Gunicorn)

Tags: django, nginx, cloud-foundry

I have Django/Gunicorn + whitenoise (for static files serving) working as a single app in Cloud Foundry using the following manifest.yml file:

```
---
applications:
- name: mydjango
  instances: 1
  command: src/tvpv_portal/bin/start_gunicorn_django.sh
  memory: 2048M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpacks:
    - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git
  stack: cflinuxfs3
  env:
    DJANGO_MODE: Production
```

For learning/experimentation, I would like to remove whitenoise and setup Nginx using the nginx_buildpack to work with Django/Gunicorn. However, I am not sure how to use multiple buildpacks on a single app. I have created a `nginx.conf`, `mime.types`, and `buildpack.yml` in my project directory following the directions at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/index.html.

nginx.conf

```
daemon off;

error_log /home/vcap/app/nginx-error.log;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
    access_log /home/vcap/app/nginx-access.log cloudfoundry;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    include mime.types;

    sendfile on;
    gzip on;

    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    port_in_redirect off; # Ensure that redirects don't include the internal container PORT - 8080

    server {
        listen {{port}};
        server_name localhost;

        # Serve static files.
        location /static/ {
            alias /home/vcap/app/src/tvpv_portal/static/;
        }

        # Serve media files.
        location /media/ {
            alias /home/vcap/app/src/tvpv_portal/media/;
        }

        # Reverse proxy to forward to main app.
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing `cf push mydjango -b nginx_buildpack -b python_buildpack`. But from looking at the docs it seems that only the last buildpack is able to launch the command. The commands from the preceding buildpacks are ignored. Hence, I am not able to get the nginx server to start. How do I get multiple buildpacks setup properly?

I did read [CloudFoundry: nginx for serving static content on top of Gunicorn (Docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973747/cloudfoundry-nginx-for-serving-static-content-on-top-of-gunicorn-docker) but the response is about having two separate apps with different routes. Since this is more for learning/experimentation with CF, I am wondering if it is possible to do it with a single app without separating out the static content. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I will try experimenting with two apps. One for nginx. One for Django/Gunicorn and have them talk through each other via their domain address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production workloads (or anything important), you really don't want to put multiple logically separate processes into one container. The primary reason is that this makes it difficult to scale your app. Let's say your app gets popular and you need more Django processing to handle the load, with both Nginx & Django in the same container you have to scale up both together. If they are separate apps, you can scale them independently as needed for each logical process.

There are other pain points as well:

- CPU & Memory management is trickier. You have multiple processes competing for the same pool of resources. This is particularly tricky for Java apps, where the JVM likes to take *all* the memory. This means you have to estimate better so that you don't exhaust memory can cause your app to crash.
- It is more complicated to correctly respond to health checks. Your health check needs to accurately represent that your app is "working". With multiple processes in the same app, that is more difficult.
- It is tricky to make the app exit when one of those processes dies. This is similar to getting the health check right. If the app doesn't completely exit, then the app won't be restarted and you can be left with half an app, or a broken app that can't be automatically restarted/fixed.
- You have more flexibility with two separate apps, specifically you can update apps independently.

At any rate, if you're still thinking you want to stuff both into the same app you have a couple options.

1. You can simply take control of the start command with `cf push -c` or by adding `command:` into manifest.yml. This will allow you to override the command set by the final buildpack. Just be careful as it will completely override what is set by the buildpack, so you really need to know the right command to invoke or your app will not start (this is particularly tricky with Java apps where the start command can be complex).
2. You can drop a `.profile` file into the root of your application directory (i.e. where you set `cf push -p`). This script will execute prior to the command set by the final buildpack and you can use it to launch other processes in the background.

As mentioned above, it is particularly tricky to get both processes to exit correctly when you use the methods above. This is one hack I've found that helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

run_second_process() {
    # insert the command to run the second process here
    #   it should run and keep running (i.e. foreground)
    nginx -c nginx.conf
    # should never get to here, if it does the app crashed
    pkill python  # insert name of your primary process
    # now we are all dead and the container will restart
}

# runs the second process in the background
#   that is important otherwise the primary process will never run
run_updater &
```

You will need to figure out ways to work around the other shortcomings, or just switch to using multiple apps.